Travelling Saleman Problem (TSP) to browse a polygons list
I am looking for a TSP variant is order to make a drone trajectory "draw" all polygons in the shortest distance without crossing the external blue polygon:

(This is made to create flight plan scanning for a drone)
In a mathematical way, the TSP nodes will be polygons and the drone will draw the whole polygon every time but it can start to any node of it (and will end at the same node). It also is allowed to pass twice by a single node.
Do you have sample codes / similar implementations / research paper on the subject ?
I preferably using python, networkx and shapely.
For now my polygon is:
polygon = [
    [0, 0],
    [100, 0],
    [100, 100],
    [0, 100],
    [-300, 55],
    [-300, 50],
    [85, 50],
    [0, 0]
]

To generate inbounds polygon:
def generate_offset_polygons(polygon, radius):
    offset_polygons = []
    current_polygon = polygon
    while current_polygon.is_valid and not current_polygon.is_empty:
        current_polygon = current_polygon.buffer(-radius)
        if current_polygon.is_valid and not current_polygon.is_empty:
            offset_polygons.append(current_polygon)
    polygons = [polygon] + offset_polygons

    segments = []
    for poly in polygons:
        if isinstance(poly, Polygon):
            segments.append(add_polygon(poly, radius))
        elif isinstance(poly, MultiPolygon):
            for subpoly in poly.geoms:  # Correctly iterate over the polygons in the MultiPolygon
                segments.append(add_polygon(subpoly, radius))
    return segments

To sample poyligons
def add_polygon(poly_shape, radius):
    x, y = poly_shape.exterior.xy
    points = numpy.array([x, y]).T
    points_valid = [points[0]]
    for point in points[1:]:
        x1, y1 = point
        x2, y2 = points_valid[-1]
        distance = ((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)**0.5
        if distance > 1:
            points_valid.append(point)
    return points_valid


This looks quite similar to the robot vacuum cleaner travel algorithms
